# How does Buddhism define abortion?

Tags: karma, philosophy, five-precepts, ethics

Abortion is a much-debated topic, and religion frequently plays a role in any such discussion.

How does abortion fit into Buddhist faith?

Is it considered negative karma by definition, or perhaps negative karma, depending upon the situation (e.g. in a family that cannot afford to properly support and raise a new child, or in the case of an abortion to save the life of the mother)?

Are there definitions of when human life begins tied with Buddhism?

Comment: Seung Sahn talked about this from the point-of-view of intention and harm - see http://thebuddhistblog.blogspot.co.uk/2010/05/zen-master-seung-sahn-on-abortion.html

Comment: This modern-secular buddhist, defines life as "sentient beings". So informed by science, fetus's appear able to think around 4 months after conception. However, this is an answer that likely pleases no one.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of [Are Buddhists Against Abortion](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/1402/32), which covers both when "life" from the standpoint of Buddhism begins and how abortion specifically is handled.

Answer (score 2):

In Buddhism, life starts at the moment of conception. So abortion breaks the 1st precept and causes bad Karma no matter how you try to justify it. Even if the husband's intention is to save the wife(mother), it still causes bad Karma. To give you an analogy, let's say a bear captured your wife and is about to kill her. Say you have a gun with you. You can shoot the bear and save your wife, but it still breaks the 1st precept and causes bad Karma.

Comment: Isn't allowing the death of your wife also bad karma? Where is the intention is your example? I see the intention not to harm the bear however if given little choice to save another life, who are you or me to play judge, jury and executioner?

Comment: Then you are karmicly responsible for the child who died today in Africa due to starvation. Because you did not send the money you used on buying new clothes, furniture etc. to feed him or her. :) Karma has nothing to do with how others judge you. It's a natural law. Not a God who judges you.

Comment: In the context of your example, we are all responsible for the child that died today in Africa no matter the reason for the child's death. The fact that you distinguish child, you and me suggests polarity of you, me and them. Since we are all connected, we all bear some responsibility. The concept of judgement is interesting. Are you suggesting that karma/kamma are the judge and jury? If so, again, it suggests the concept of a sculptor and sculpture. Natural law it may be, however if judgement is being place, how is it being achieved?

Comment: "we are all responsible for the child that died" - Maybe according to some socialism theory. But not Karmicly.
Karma is not a judge. Just like gravity is not a judge. Killing the bear requires aversion. A thought with aversion is bad Karma,and taking a life breaks the precept even if it was preceded by a thought to save the wife.

Comment: This response isn't intended to offend. It is an inquiry to your statements. How do you know for certain what has negative or positive karmic consequences? I am intrigued by the comment on socialism since if we are truly all connected the fact that one ignores a child that died or is dying, is in my view irresponsible for all concerned. Just because one is not directly affected by it, does not equate to lessened responsibility. If this responsibility is denied, it is aversion by definition.

Comment: I am not attempting to justify the killing of an animal nor any sentient being, since unless all the rules are openly known, none of us are in the position to pass comment of what has positive, negative or neutral karmic consequence.

Comment: "since if we are truly all connected" - This sounds like the universal soul theory. It is a Hindu concept.
"If this responsibility is denied, it is aversion by definition" - no that is not the definition of aversion. Aversion is the disliking towards an object received by your senses.

Comment: All the topics are constructs or concepts and if they are realized they differ for all of us so labelling it Hindu, Buddhist, etc polarizes the topic. Is the definition you have provided a universal definition?

Comment: That sounds like the belief "All religions are the same". Answers given here are according to Buddhism.  I'm not sure what you mean by universal definition. Do you mean a definition accepted by all religions?

Comment: I am saying that there should be no polarity i.e. this and that. If there is a need for one, i would be keen to understand why. When i say universal definition and if i were to limit it to Buddhism, is the description you provided accepted as universal truth?

Comment: It depends on what you really mean by polarity. Are you denying opposing teachings by that? ex: There's right and there's wrong. Good and evil. Hinduism believes in Atman. Buddhism teaches Anathma. Hinduism believes in a creator god and a universal soul. Buddhism rejects that. 
The pali word is ['Dosa'](http://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/do%E1%B9%A3a/index.html). Aversion, anger, hatred, disliking are the commonly accepted English words for it. Obviously the disliking is towards an object received by your senses.

Comment: When i say polarity, it's the contrast in this context multiple interpretations. Are you saying that aversion can only be the result of the 5 senses?

Comment: Well, that's why there are different religions and even different Buddhist schools.
It is impossible to dislike anything other than what you receive by the 6 senses.